# Cannot implicently convert type 'string' to 'bool' JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq

Hi I need help finding a value from a Object list that I created form aJSON file :

JSON Structure :

```
{
    "mp": "1",
    "mpuus": [
      {
        "id": "100",
        "tpuus": [
          "000000001",
          "000000002"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "101",
        "tpuus": [
          "00000003"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "mp": "2",
    "mpuus": [
      {
        "id": "200",
        "tpuus": [
          "0000004"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

I convert JSON to

```
 RootMedicationMapping object.
List<rootMedicationMapping> = JsonHandler.DeserializeJasonArrayFromFile<RootMedicationMapping>(@"JSON File PATH");
```

I would like to search the list of **rootMedicationMapping** by the tpuu value and get the mp value.

e.g the value I am passing is tpuu = 000000002, I want to get back the mp value (1 in this case)

This am trying the below syntax but it isthrowing me

> 'Cannot implicently convert type 'string' to 'bool'

```
var mpId= rootMedicationMapping.Find(x => x.MPUUs.Find(y=>y.Tpuus.Find(z=>z.Equals("tpuu value"))));
```

Comment: Q: Could you post `RootMedicationMapping`?  It sounds like you've declared mp as "bool" ... but your JSON clearly uses it as a "string".  Legal "bool" values in your JSON would definitely include `true` (without quotes), might include `1` (without quotes) ... but definitely *NOT* `"1"`.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of [List.Find(Predicate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=net-5.0#definition) needs to be a [Predicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=net-5.0) which is a delegate that takes in an instance of the object you're searching and expects a bool returned specifying if the object matches. Currently, in the Predicate of your inner Find calls you're simply returning the result of another Find call, which is a *string* and not the expected *bool*, resulting in the error you're seeing.

To fix this, you just need to make sure the Predicate arguments return bool. With what you have, you can just add checks whether or not the inner Find calls return `null`:

```cs
var mpId = 
    rootMedicationMapping.Find(x => 
        x.MPUUs.Find(y => 
            y.Tpuus.Find(z => 
                z.Equals("tpuu value")) != null) != null)?.mp;
```

And you could also write this using LINQ, allowing the null checks to be handled by `Any`:

```cs
var mpId = 
    rootMedicationMapping.FirstOrDefault(x => 
        x.MPUUs.Any(y => 
            y.Tpuus.Any(z => 
                z.Equals("tpuu value"))))?.mp;
```